# Arduino scroll on sparkfun 2x16 LCD

Tags: c, scroll, arduino, lcd

When I want to display something that is greater then 32 characters. I want the LCD to scroll, I have already tried command flag `0x10` can someone point me to the right direction.

Comment: you could try asking on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/. Or implement your own scrolling (put the second line as the first line, and new line as second line).

Answer (score 0):

You havent indicated whether you are trying to scroll horizontally or vertically.

Horizontal scrolling is native in the lcd library.  Use autoscroll or scrollDisplayLeft/Right

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16,2);
 }

void loop() {

// set the cursor to (16,1):
lcd.setCursor(16,1);
// set the display to automatically scroll:
lcd.autoscroll();
// print from 0 to 9:
for (int thisChar = 0; thisChar < 10; thisChar++) {
 lcd.print(thisChar);
 delay(500);
}
// turn off automatic scrolling
lcd.noAutoscroll();

// clear screen for the next loop:
lcd.clear();
}
```

For vertical scrolling, you'll need to manually create an action to copy the text from line 2 to line 1 and populate line 2 with the new text.